# How do I make a REST query in python with a comparison statement?

Tags: python, rest, python-requests

How do I make a REST query in python with a comparison statement? Like (in quasi code):

```
result = foo where bar > 10
```

I want to make a rest api query from python 2.7 using requests. What I want is to get all articles that have been updated during the last 24 hours.
In javascript it looks like this and it works great:

```
http://myDatabase.domain.io/api/v1/article/q={"update_date":{"$gt":"2018-08-27 13:44"}}
```

I just can't recreate this with python. Does anyone know how?

Comment: Is it actually `/q=` or `/?q=`?

Comment: Please post a MCVE

Comment: It is `/q=`, or at least according to the guy that gave me that snippet and told me it "works great"...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming

- that's actually `?q=`, i.e. a query string
- and the query should be JSON (it looks like it)
- and the endpoint returns JSON:

---

```
import requests, json

query = json.dumps(
    {"update_date": {"$gt": "2018-08-27 13:44"}}
)
resp = requests.get(
    url="http://myDatabase.domain.io/api/v1/article/",
    params={"q": query},
)
resp.raise_for_status()
data = resp.json()
print(data)
```

Comment: Thanks! I will test this and let you know how it went

Comment: In the end this is what got it working. It was an error in the original query string as you pointed out, a / instead of a ? `url = "http://myDatabase.domain.io/api/v1/article"

querystring = json.dumps(
    {'q':{'update_date':{'gt':'2018-08-27 13:44'}}}
)

headers = {
    'Cache-Control': "no-cache"
    }

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)

print(response.text)`